# Select orders from the same customers which were ordered at different dates

Tags: mysql

I tried this command in MYSQL workbench to select the orders from the same customers (same customerID ) which were ordered at different dates: but it is not working correctly: what´s the mistake?

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE customerID = customerID AND shipmentDate != shipmentDate;
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE customerID = customerID` should do it. Also define "*not working correctly*"

Comment: ok - it´s just an example: I want to know, why the "shipmentDate != shipmentDate" is not working correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table T1,TABLE T2 WHERE T1.customerID = T2.customerID AND T1.shipmentDate <> T2.shipmentDate;
```

Comment: but it´s pretty slow (for my big data set) - is there a faster possibility?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner could you add the structure of your table(s) to your question?